# Link .xib to storyboard in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, xib

I have some views (.xib) linked to his controllers. 
I have a main storyboard too.

How can I link the xib files to the main storyboard? I need call from one view to another

Comment: Your question is not clearly enough, what is "his controllers"?

Comment: @lee5783 The .swift files containing the code functions.

Comment: You mean "You want to embed .xib file to storyboard and using it like a component (e.g: UILabel, UIButton...)"?

Comment: @lee5783 I need to link the main view (home) that is in the Storyboard with .xib views

Comment: Then, you can't do it, Apple doest allow linking between storyboard and .xib